# Highcharts columns with index on each column bottom

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I'm using highcharts `v.16.0.2` and I want to use a column chart as tank level. This mean that each column have a color depending the value... Like a traffic light (green OK, yellow Warning and red Danger).

Doing in this way, the legend is not useful. In order to do the legend useful I decided to remove the color of the legend with css, and display a number corresponding with the index of each column.

[image: tank level]

However, to be useful I need to add an extra label to each column with the index. And these labels should be displayed on the bottom:

[image: tank level with indexes]

Nevertheless, I don't know how to do it without touch the current behavior / size of each column. If I group them into just 1 serie with categories:

- The legend is showing only 1 serie
- Size of the columns are different

Another alternative that I thought is to just use another label (as is for the value), but I see that highchart only support 1 dataLabel.. I can use CSS... But I don't know how to do it to keep the value on the center and the index on the bottom.

Any idea?

Here is the highcharts config:

url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-example-columns?file=config.js

```js
{
  "chart": {
    "type": "column",
    "zoomType": "x",
    "time": {
      "timezoneOffset": 60
    },
    "height": 620,
    "events": {}
  },
  "colors": [
    "#BD1315",
    "#06bea8",
    "#BD1315",
    "#06bea8"
  ],
  "title": {
    "text": "Example of chart"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": null
    },
    "labels": {
      "style": {
        "fontSize": "10px"
      }
    }
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "max": 97.69,
    "title": {
      "text": ""
    },
    "plotLines": [
      {
        "color": "black",
        "dashStyle": "solid",
        "width": 2,
        "zIndex": 9,
        "label": {}
      },
      {
        "color": "black",
        "dashStyle": "solid",
        "width": 2,
        "zIndex": 9,
        "label": {}
      }
    ],
    "startOnTick": false
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "bar": {
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "animation": false,
      "events": {}
    },
    "column": {
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": true,
        "allowOverlap": true,
        "padding": 0,
        "inside": true,
        "useHTML": true
      },
      "animation": false,
      "events": {}
    }
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "layout": "horizontal"
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "1. Concentration of CO2 in BA (%)",
      "data": [
        97.69
      ],
      "labels": [],
    
      "regression": false,
      "regressionSettings": {
        "type": "loess",
        "extrapolate": 0,
        "loessSmooth": 50,
        "linetype": "spline",
        "dashStyle": "shortdot",
        "color": "#7cb5ec",
        "lineWidth": 2
      },
      "visible": true
    },
    {
      "name": "2. BA_pH (N/A)",
      "data": [
        6.89
      ],
      "labels": [],
      "regression": false,
      "regressionSettings": {
        "type": "loess",
        "extrapolate": 0,
        "loessSmooth": 50,
        "linetype": "spline",
        "dashStyle": "shortdot",
        "color": "#434348",
        "lineWidth": 2
      },
      "visible": true
    },
    {
      "name": "3. BCN_AgitatorSpeed (rpm)",
      "data": [
        40
      ],
      "labels": [],
      "regression": false,
      "regressionSettings": {
        "type": "loess",
        "extrapolate": 0,
        "loessSmooth": 50,
        "linetype": "spline",
        "dashStyle": "shortdot",
        "color": "#90ed7d",
        "lineWidth": 2
      },
      "visible": true
    },
    {
      "name": "4. BCN_O2_Concentration (%)",
      "data": [
        7.5
      ],
      "labels": [],
      "regression": false,
      "regressionSettings": {
        "type": "loess",
        "extrapolate": 0,
        "loessSmooth": 50,
        "linetype": "spline",
        "dashStyle": "shortdot",
        "color": "#f7a35c",
        "lineWidth": 2
      },
      "visible": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "If I group them into just 1 serie with categories: The legend is showing only 1 serie" Yes, but so what? If the categories are labelled on the chart directly, this is better than a legend, and you don't really need a legend. (if the chart is labeled directly, the user doesn't have to look back and forth to figure out which series is which) "...Size of the columns are different" The layout of the columns will be different than they are with multiple series, yes, but you can control all of the layout parameters using things like `pointPadding`, `groupPadding`, `pointRange`, `columnWidth`, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, the legend should appear displaying all items (UX team decision)... With only 4 columns are okey, but with more the categories with all the text is easy to overlap with other. This is why both behavior should be applied: Index on the bottom (no name) + legend

Comment: For the record, it's a very poor UX team decision. If more series force issues with the column labels, the best UX decision is to make it a horizontal bar chart which allows more room for the labels. Not sure of a good way to set up what you're asking for without getting complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set different `x` data value for each series. Additionally, you will have to disable `grouping` for series and set xAxis type as `category`:

```
"series": [{
        "data": [
            {x: 1, y: 97.69}
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {x: 2, y: 6.89}
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {x: 3, y: 40}
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {x: 4, y: 7.5}
        ]
    }
]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mc1bt98n/

Comment: this was just what I was find! Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2):

As an example of my comment:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/wy24bq9c/

Using `categories`, and setting the data in one series:

```
"series": [{
    "data": [
        {"y": 97.69, "color": "#BD1315"},
        {"y": 6.89, "color": "#06bea8"},
        {"y": 40, "color": "#BD1315"},
        {"y": 7.5,"color": "#06bea8"},
    ]
}]
```

Allows the labels to be directly on the chart and removes the need for an extraneous and redundant legend, while at the same time making it easier for the user to understand which series is which.

Using the `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` settings, you can control the width and spacing of the columns:

```
"plotOptions": {
        "column": {
      "pointPadding": 0.2,
      "groupPadding": 0,
       ...
```

**Example:**

[image: example output]